Portfolio Construction
Consider a one-factor pricing model where the dependent variable is the spread
between a 5y Credit Default Swaps index and the 5y Treasury Note, while the
factor is a stock market index. Assume that you estimate a negative coefficient
for the factor. If one day you observe the spread located more than two standard
deviations above the regression line, what portfolio do you build with positions on
the CDS index, the Treasury Note and the stock market index?
How will approach this question and explain, please.

Hi: It's an interesting question. Obviously, you would like to short the spread because one expects it to come down eventually. But, at the same time, you need a hedge because, if the market goes down, then the spread widens which is not good for a short of the spread. So, I'm not sure how you deal with that hedging part. Hopefully, someone else knows how. So, in summary, you want to be not effected by the market's effect on the spread but, at the same time, capture the expected eventually decline in the spread. Also, since no one answered, you want to eventually send to quant.stackexchange.
